# how to set asp:HyperLink href to "mailto:abc@hotmail.com" in .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how can I set the asp:HyperLink href to "mailto:abc@hotmail.com" in .net c#?

Example:
If I have the following code:

```
  <tr>
    <td class="graytext r">PERSONAL EMAIL:</td>
    <td><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="sPersonalEmail" class="orange" style="cursor:pointer" /></td>
  </tr>
```

How can I set the href to "mailto:abc@hotmail.com" in .net c# instead of hard code it in asp:HyperLink?

Comment: what did you try and which results did you get ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this by setting `NavigateUrl`:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Email", "mailto:{0}") %>'
                              Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'
                              ID="hlEmail">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this the easiest

```
string whateverEmail = "test@this.com";

hypEmail.Attributes.Add("href", "mailto:" + whateverEmail );
```

Comment: Don't forget to add this line: hypEmail.Text = whateverEmail;

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it code behind then you could simply put the following in page load (or wherever relevant, such as a button event):

string email = "abc@hotmail.com";
sPersonalEmail.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + email;

Answer (score 1):

Another way is this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" DataFormatString="<a href=mailto:{0}>{0}</a>" HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my ASP.NET code using the asp:HyperLink properties.

```
 hlEmail.Text = "theEmail@webAddess.com";
 hlEmail.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + "theEmail@webAddess.com";
```