# Is there way to concatenate asp.net control with html mailto: to send email?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, mailto

I am reading an Email from database columns successfully and assigning it to a asp Label control's text property.

When I run the page in browser and label populates with email, I am trying open an outlook window by some way concatenating the mailto: and the label's text property value. (similar functionality what we do with html mailto:.

Can somebody please advise how I combine or concatenate the mailto and the label value so that when I click on that email it opens email editor window?

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357189/how-to-set-asphyperlink-href-to-mailtoabchotmail-com-in-net-c-sharp

Comment: I tried those options. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
lblOutput1.Text = "<a href=\"mailto:xxx@gmail.com\">xxx@gmail.com</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you user3065011. I did something similar and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my question, I have Email value that I am retrieving from the database.

What I did is explained below:

**on .aspx page:**
1. Took an anchor tag and set it runat="server".
2. Took an html label and set it runat="server" and placed it in between anchor's opening and closing tag.

**on .aspx.cs page:**
1. declare a string variable and assign database value to it.
2. assign database value to the label's innerHtml property.
3. Finally, I wrote this line: 
anchormail.Attributes.Add("href", "mailto:" + mail);